# Size of interline in pt?

Tags: size

I need to write a document with a font of `12pt` and `18pt` of interline (EXACTLY). I used the `\linespread{X}\selectfont` command line to increase the interline size... but I do not know how much I must put for X to have `18pt`. Do you know how to properly define X to get `18pt` for each interline ?

Thanks !

Comment: How about `\documentclass[12pt]{article} \usepackage{leading} \leading{18pt} ...`

Comment: Do you mean you want 18pt from the deepest possible descender on a line and the highest possible ascender on the next one?

Comment: The fact with the `\linespread{X}\selectfont` is that you don't need to use another package. But if no one else find the answer I will come back to your advice Clemens. But One question, does it works for the whole document ?

Comment: Egreg, I don't get your question. I didn't know there was an abiguite using the word "interline" :/

Comment: You can do `\fontsize{12pt}{18pt}\selectfont` at the beginning of your text, but some environments may reset it.  For example `\begin{document}` does.  This gives 18pt baseline to baseline.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When metal type was used, characters were cut on pieces of metal having all the same size, independent of ascenders and descenders

[image]

Source: http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/The_EM_Square.html
(Note that the picture has been mirrored in order to ease reading.)

Lines could be spaced by inserting strips of metal (mostly made of lead, so “leading”).

TeX uses a different model for this, because it just aligns characters by their reference point, so its model is different: it tries to keep a fixed distance between baselines (the amount of the current `\baselineskip`).

What 18pt leading means is rather ambiguous. As you see, in the picture there is no leading, but the characters don't touch: “yp” is just above “th”, but there's some space between them. This is because the height of the piece carrying a character is greater than the sum of maximum height and maximum depth among all characters (the same length as a *strut*).

So you could refer to 18pt between the deepest possible descender on a line and the highest possible ascender on the next line; or you could measure the 18pt from the depth and height of a strut. This will give quite different results.

The suggested `leading` package can solve the issue, because it allows specifying the baseline distance in points, rather than computing a factor for `\linespread`. However, a simplistic

```
\leading{18pt}
```

will not do:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{leading}

\leading{18pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\llap{\smash{%
  \vrule height0pt depth \fontchardp\font`y \hskip 1pt
  \vrule height0pt depth \dimexpr\fontchardp\font`y + 18pt\relax
}}by\\
by

\end{document}
```

[image]

The image makes clear that 18pt is the baselineskip.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{leading}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settoheight{\dimen0}{%
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%
  }%
  \settodepth{\dimen2}{%
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%
  }%
  \leading{\dimexpr18pt+\dimen0+\dimen2}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\llap{\smash{%
  \vrule height0pt depth \fontchardp\font`y \hskip 1pt
  \vrule height0pt depth \dimexpr\fontchardp\font`y + 18pt\relax
}}by\\
by

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now there are exactly 18pt from the bottom of the y to the top of the b.

If you use accented uppercase characters, you might have to fix the alphabet used for measuring the maximum height and depth.

Comment: IMHO, the picture with metal types should be mirrored.

Comment: @wipet I took that from the site; it *is* mirrored! :-)

Comment: The picture from the site must be mirrored in order it illustrate the reality. This was the meaning of my first comment. Note the logo at the typo-rule.

Comment: Isn't the most common use of *leading* the meaning “the distance between the baselines of successive lines of type” (despite the origin of the word)?

Comment: @clemens The original meaning was the thickness of the metal strips.

Comment: @egreg I know. But nevertheless that's not what it means today, right?

Answer (score 3):

TeX uses three primitive registers which control the interline spaces. First of them is `\baselineskip`. If the two followed lines are not overlapped in sense of `\lineskiplimit` register then `\baselineskip` is used as the distance of two following baselines. The "overlapping in sense of `\lineskiplimit` register" (it is set to 0pt by default but it should be positive or [more usual] negative) means: the distance between biggest descender in the first line and the biggest ascender in the second line (when the rule with `\baselineskip` is tried) is greater or equal to `\lineskiplimit`. If such condition is not true then `\baselineskip` is not used for these two lines at all, but the `\lineskip` is inserted between such lines (default 1pt by plain TeX).

Examples: if you set `\lineskiplimit` to sufficient negative value then all lines have `\baselineskip` distance independent of they are overlapped or not.

If you set `\lineskiplimit` and `\baselineskip` to 0pt then `\lineskip` is inserted between all lines and the baseline grid is typically lost.

Note, that `\baselineskip` nad `\lineskip` are "skip" registers (they may include stretchability and/or shrinkability) but `\lineskiplimit` is "dimen" register.